# How do I insert column in mssql with java

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I don't insert column in mssql with java. Which do I use method ,How do I use? 
Thanks

Comment: Answer is 42. Or the question is not fit for this site... Please read the [FAQ], and post what you tried...

Comment: It is always good to share what have you tried to get quick and better help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can simply use a [SQL DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statement :

```
//st is a Java JDBC Statement object ...
st.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD yourcolumn int");
```

Comment: I upvote this because something may sound trivial for us but may be too tough for a beginer. I would suggest to add complete sample to help the user.

Answer (score 0):

Load the driver, establish connection.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://servername;database=databasename;integratedSecurity=true");
```

Create a statement and execute it.

```
Statement statement = connection .createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumnName DataType");
```